# Passing data from completion block to view controller swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

!I have been stuck for 2 days on this issue. Here is my scenario.

User clicks login button, if email address and password are stored in `UserDefaults`, the app silently login the user in, first presenting an `UIAlertController` while retrieving the user's data from the server. Once the data is returned to the app, a completion handler assigns a local property `var User: [String: AnyObject]` the results. I can `print(self.User)` at this point and the data is properly assigned. All good. The problem occur when I try to pass this data to the next controller that I am presenting via `present`. Here is my code:

```
LoginViewController.swift

-----

    dismiss(animated:true, completion: {
        let tenantViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"tenantDashboardViewController") as! TenantDashboardViewController
        tenantViewController.User = user
        print(tenantViewController.User) //Works
        self.present(tenantViewController, animated: true)
     })
```

Here is my destination viewcontroller

```
import Foundation
import SideMenuController

class TenantDashboardViewController: SideMenuController {


    var User: [String: AnyObject]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTenantDashboardHomeViewController", sender: nil)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "containTenantSideMenu", sender: nil)

        print(self.User!) //Always returns nil, crashes app

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try passing data in `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`.

Comment: Also side note: You should not be storing sensitive user data like passwords in `UserDefaults`. Use the Keychain.

Comment: @MattSeaman Thank you. I will do that.

Comment: @triple.s I'll add the prepare to the destination view controller?

Comment: No.. in the source view controller.. in your case `LoginViewController`. Remember you are preparing to land in your destination `viewcontroller`. Therefore you need all your preparation beforehand :D (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31934786/2301570)

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I think I'll try what @brandonscript suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're storing a user object app-side, you should store the *User Object* in `NSUserDefaults`. Make it `NSCoding` compliant so you can encode/decode the User class as you need to.

Then, as Matthew states, store your username/password combo in Keychain, because it is extremely sensitive and Keychain is designed to protect your users' credentials in a secure way.

Comment: I upvoted this because this is exactly what I need to do. Thank you!